# How to prove that if there's a solution to $A_{m \times n}x=b$, $b \in R^m$ and $n \le m$ then $A$'s columns are a base in $R^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that if there's a solution to $A_{m \times n}x=b$, $b \in R^m$ and $n \le m$ then $A$'s columns are a base in $R^m$. I don't understand how this can be. A base in $F^n$ has to have at least $n$ vectors while it's given that $n \le m$.

Comment: I  think in your original question, Ax=b has solution for all b, otherwise your claim is not true (take A=0 and b=0 as a counter example)

Comment: @nonlinearthought $x$ and $b$ are a vector.

Comment: I know,  Did I say "they are not vectors" !?

Answer (score 0):

$Ax$ means the linear combination of columns of A, where scalar coefficients comes from the components of the vector $x$! So if there exists $x$ such that $Ax=b$ this means the vector $b$ can be written as linear combination of columns of $A.$  Therefore columns of $A$ generates $R^m$, and since $n$ is less that or equal $m$, they have to linearly independent.

Comment: Can you please explain how this proves that $A$ is linearly independent and spans $R^m$, which is the definition of base?

Comment: I didn't understand how you concluded that $A$ is linearly independent. I know that for $A{m \times n}$ ${a_1,a_2,...,a_n} \in \mathbb{F^n}$ if $n > m$ then $A$ is linearly dependent. Also if $A$ is linearly independent then $n \le m$ but not the other way around.